# Can I force my company to pay me in Bitcoin

Tags: legal, banks, salary

I just got my bank account closed.

> Reason: International payment were not supported

I don't like to waste my time in bank formalities. I am a programmer. I wish to stay technical for most of the part.

Comment: If you are Indian, read https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=1320939.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not - I mean you're not in an absolute position to demand them to compensate you via bitcoin.  Can you possibly get an E-checking account with someone like INGDirect then have your BTC automatically dispursed via bitwage or even lawnmower...I think you could even do an auto-rebuy with coinbase if you felt inclined to do so.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can ask nicely, but unless your company operates in a country that has declared Bitcoin [legal tender](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legal_tender) you have no legal grounds to enforce it.

Comment: Bitcoin is legal in India. Govt. Supports it

Comment: @AbhimanyuAryan: Bitcoin being legal, and Bitcoin being "legal tender" are two vastly different things.

Answer (score -4):

Paolo from [BITWAGE](https://www.bitwage.com/) here; we at Bitwage can help you get paid in bitcoin without your employer even knowing you are availing of our Bitcoin Payroll Service and earning a "bit wage" from Bitwage.

HOW IT WORKS: 1. We give you a bank account number. 2. You tell your employer to send any percentage of your payroll deposit to that number. 3. We put bitcoin, local currency in your preferred bitcoin wallet address the next day after deposit.

If you have further questions or need help with the sign up, please feel free to reach out to me anytime at: paolo.huelgas@bitwage.com

Comment: This has been flagged as spam several times. In this case I disagree: The answer describes a valid way of countering the problem the asker describes. Per our guidelines this answer may adhere to what is described as "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, so be it. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers.". @Paolo: I hope you will also contribute in other ways on our site. If you are just here to advertise your product, please talk to the Stackexchange team for an advertising contract.

Comment: That said, please take a [tour] to understand how Stack Exchange network works. Also, take a moment to understand [how to not be a spammer](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/help/promotion).